# Querying List in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like below in Snowflake

```
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|attrs          |options                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|acct           |[{"key":"spencer","val":"spencer"},{"key":"mart","val":"mart"},{"key":"red-fin","val":"-"}]                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|fav_activity   |[{"key":"movie","val":"movie"},{"key":"books","val":"books"},{"key":"music","val":"music"},{"key":"swimming","val":"swimming"},{"key":"games","val":"games"},{"key":"team","val":"team"},{"key":"food","val":"food"},{"key":"steam-room","val":"\"steam room\""},{"key":"hiking","val":"hiking"}]  |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I need to compare each key and val of the list of dictionaries and return only key of the dictionary whose key/val are distinct.

For example, looking at the attrs `acct` - There are 3 dictionaries in the list. The key and val of the first two dictionaries are identical but the third one has distinct key/val values. So I need to return the key of the third dict which is `red-fin`

Expected output :

```
+---------------+------------+
|attrs          |result      |
+---------------+------------+   
|acct           |red-fin     |
|fav_activity   |steam-room  |
+---------------+------------+
```

Can someone help me doing this in Snowflake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to flatten and compare.

This solves it for the example test case:

```sql
with data as (
select $1 attrs, parse_json($2) options   
from values ('acct', '[{"key":"spencer","val":"spencer"},{"key":"mart","val":"mart"},{"key":"red-fin","val":"-"}]')
, ('fav_activity', '[{"key":"movie","val":"movie"},{"key":"books","val":"books"},{"key":"music","val":"music"},{"key":"swimming","val":"swimming"},{"key":"games","val":"games"},{"key":"team","val":"team"},{"key":"food","val":"food"},{"key":"steam-room","val":"\\"steam room\\""},{"key":"hiking","val":"hiking"}]')
)

select attrs, k.value:key
from data, table(flatten(options)) k
where k.value:key!=k.value:val
;
```

[image]